# Select Column A or B based on a matching value

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I need to extract first part of the string and store it in a variable.

```
final String[] split = InputValue.split("_", 2);
final String extractedValue = split[0];
```

Now I need to do something Like this:
I need to check if the extractedValue is column Emp_Id or Emp_Name

```
"SELECT Count(*)as count,Emp_Name,Emp_Id FROM Employee WHERE extractedValue=? IN(Emp_Id,Emp_Name)";

preparedStatement.setString(1, extractedValue);
```

I am getting a error No such column in Employee table.

How to check for a matching column  value here?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, your SQL is strange, because you are returning `COUNT(*)` along with two columns that are not aggregated.

The syntax for what you want is:

```
SELECT Count(*) as count, Emp_Name, Emp_Id
FROM Employee
WHERE ? IN (Emp_Id, Emp_Name);
```

However, I would remove `Emp_Name` and `Emp_Id` from the `SELECT`.  Or perhaps do:

```
SELECT Count(*) as count,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Emp_Name) as Emp_Names,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Emp_Id) as Emp_Ids
FROM Employee
WHERE ? IN (Emp_Id, Emp_Name);
```